# Chart.js The second line in Chart.js is incorrectly positioned in X-axis

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, chart.js

I have created multiple line chart, but the second line incorrectly positioned according X-axis, got the same starting point as first line, but by JsonData it has another starting point. How to fix it? No idea.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4Mzu.png)

Function of creating chart:

```
function createEmployeeChart(chartId, xValues, datasets) {
                  var uniqueXValues = Array.from(new Set(xValues));
                
                  new Chart(chartId, {
                    type: "line",
                    data: {
                      labels: uniqueXValues,
                      datasets: datasets,
                    },
                    options: {
                      legend: {
                        display: false
                      },
                    },
                  });
                }
```

Ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/statistics/handlers/candidates/show_candidates_graph_by_employee.php",
                data: {
                  startDate: startDate,
                  endDate: endDate,
                  departments: departments,
                  stage: stage,
                  responsible_id: responsible_id,
                },
                success: function (data) {
                  var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);

                  if (responsible_id === undefined) {

                    var employeeIds = Object.keys(jsonData);

                    // Initialize startDateArray as an empty array
                    var startDateArray = [];

                    // Populate startDateArray inside the map function
                    var datasets = employeeIds.map(function (employeeId, index) {
                      var employeeData = jsonData[employeeId];

                      var firstName = employeeData[0].firstName;
                      var lastName = employeeData[0].lastName;

                      // Use push to add elements to the existing array
                      employeeData.forEach(function (item) {
                        var parsedStartDate = moment(item.startDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD H:i:s');
                        var parsedEndDate = moment(item.endDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD H:i:s');
                        
                        // Check if the time difference is less than one day
                        var timeDifferenceInDays = parsedEndDate.diff(parsedStartDate, 'days');
                        var dateFormat = (timeDifferenceInDays < 1) ? 'HH:mm' : 'DD.MM';
                        
                        var formattedDate = parsedStartDate.format(dateFormat);
                        startDateArray.push(formattedDate);
                    });                    

                      var stageCountArray = employeeData.map(function (item) {
                        return parseInt(item.stageCount);
                      });

                      return {
                        label: firstName + ' ' + lastName,
                        data: stageCountArray,
                        borderColor: getRandomColor(),
                        fill: false,
                      };
                    });

                    destroyChart("employeeChart");

                    if (startDate == endDate) {
                      $('#employeeChartTitle').text('График по сотруднику: ' + startDate);
                    } else {
                      $('#employeeChartTitle').text('График по сотруднику: ' + startDate + ' | ' + endDate);
                    }

                    createEmployeeChart("employeeChart", startDateArray, datasets, true);
                  } else {
                    // Display data for the selected responsible_id
                    var startDateArray = jsonData[responsible_id].map(function (item) {
                      var parsedDate = moment(item.startDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD H:i:s');
                      var dateFormat = (moment(item.endDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD H:i:s').diff(parsedDate, 'days') <= 0) ? 'HH:mm' : 'DD.MM';
                      return parsedDate.format(dateFormat);
                    });

                    var stageCountArray = jsonData[responsible_id].map(function (item) {
                      return parseInt(item.stageCount);
                    });

                    var firstNameArray = jsonData[responsible_id].map(function (item) {
                      return item.firstName;
                    });

                    var lastNameArray = jsonData[responsible_id].map(function (item) {
                      return item.lastName;
                    });

                    destroyChart("employeeChart");

                    if (startDate == endDate) {
                      $('#employeeChartTitle').text('График по сотруднику: ' + startDate);
                    } else {
                      $('#employeeChartTitle').text('График по сотруднику: ' + startDate + ' | ' + endDate);
                    }

                    createEmployeeChart("employeeChart", startDateArray, [{
                      label: firstNameArray[0] + ' ' + lastNameArray[0],
                      data: stageCountArray,
                      borderColor: 'green',
                      fill: false,
                    }], true); // Pass true to indicate that X-axis is startDateArray
                  }
                },
              });
```

Server script:

```
<?php
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/common/db_statistics.php');
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/common/db_auth.php');

$startDate = $_GET['startDate'];
$endDate = $_GET['endDate'];
$departments = $_GET['departments'];
$stage = $_GET['stage'];
$responsible_ids = isset($_GET['responsible_id']) ? explode(',', $_GET['responsible_id']) : [];

$data = array();

if (date('Y-m-d', strtotime($startDate)) == date('Y-m-d', strtotime($endDate))) {
    $startDate = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime($startDate));
    $endDate = date('Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime($endDate));
    $increment = '+1 hour';
} else {
    $increment = '+1 day';
}

$currentStartDate = $startDate;

while ($currentStartDate <= $endDate) {
    $startPeriod = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($currentStartDate));
    $endPeriod = date('Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime($startPeriod . $increment));

    if (!empty($responsible_ids)) {
        foreach ($responsible_ids as $responsible_id) {
            $whereClause = " AND date >= '$startPeriod' AND date <= '$endPeriod' AND responsible_id = '$responsible_id'";
            $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as stageCount FROM `bitrix` WHERE departments = '$departments' AND stage = '$stage' $whereClause";
            $r_get_created_candidate = mysqli_query($link_bitrix_statistic, $query);
    
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r_get_created_candidate)) {
                // Fetch employee information inside the loop
                $employeeInfo = mysqli_query($link_auth, "SELECT name, surname FROM users WHERE bitrix_id = '$responsible_id'");
                $employeeData = mysqli_fetch_array($employeeInfo);
    
                $firstName = $employeeData['name'];
                $lastName = $employeeData['surname'];
    
                $data[$responsible_id][] = [
                    'firstName' => $firstName,
                    'lastName' => $lastName,
                    'startDate' => $startPeriod,
                    'endDate' => $endPeriod,
                    'stageCount' => $row['stageCount'],
                ];
            }
        }
    } elseif (empty($responsible_ids)) {
        // If responsible_id is empty, retrieve data for all responsible_id values
        $whereClause = " AND date >= '$startPeriod' AND date <= '$endPeriod'";
        $query = "SELECT responsible_id, COUNT(*) as stageCount FROM `bitrix` WHERE departments = '$departments' AND stage = '$stage' $whereClause GROUP BY responsible_id";
    
        $r_get_created_candidate = mysqli_query($link_bitrix_statistic, $query);
    
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r_get_created_candidate)) {
            // Fetch employee information inside the loop
            $employeeInfo = mysqli_query($link_auth, "SELECT name, surname FROM users WHERE bitrix_id = '$row[responsible_id]'");
            $employeeData = mysqli_fetch_array($employeeInfo);
    
            $firstName = $employeeData['name'];
            $lastName = $employeeData['surname'];
    
            $data[$row['responsible_id']][] = [
                'firstName' => $firstName,
                'lastName' => $lastName,
                'startDate' => $startPeriod,
                'endDate' => $endPeriod,
                'stageCount' => $row['stageCount'],
            ];
        }
    }
    

    $currentStartDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($startPeriod . $increment));
}

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

here's example of jsonData:
347
:
[{firstName: "Замира", lastName: "Калиева", startDate: "2023-11-06 00:00:00",…},…]
0
:
{firstName: "Замира", lastName: "Калиева", startDate: "2023-11-06 00:00:00",…}
1
:
{firstName: "Замира", lastName: "Калиева", startDate: "2023-11-07 00:00:00",…}
2
:
{firstName: "Замира", lastName: "Калиева", startDate: "2023-11-08 00:00:00",…}
3
:
{firstName: "Замира", lastName: "Калиева", startDate: "2023-11-09 00:00:00",…}
4
:
{firstName: "Замира", lastName: "Калиева", startDate: "2023-11-10 00:00:00",…}
5
:
{firstName: "Замира", lastName: "Калиева", startDate: "2023-11-12 00:00:00",…}
6
:
{firstName: "Замира", lastName: "Калиева", startDate: "2023-11-13 00:00:00",…}
7
:
{firstName: "Замира", lastName: "Калиева", startDate: "2023-11-14 00:00:00",…}
8
:
{firstName: "Замира", lastName: "Калиева", startDate: "2023-11-15 00:00:00",…}
9
:
{firstName: "Замира", lastName: "Калиева", startDate: "2023-11-16 00:00:00",…}
10
:
{firstName: "Замира", lastName: "Калиева", startDate: "2023-11-17 00:00:00",…}
11
:
{firstName: "Замира", lastName: "Калиева", startDate: "2023-11-22 00:00:00",…}
12
:
{firstName: "Замира", lastName: "Калиева", startDate: "2023-11-23 00:00:00",…}
13
:
{firstName: "Замира", lastName: "Калиева", startDate: "2023-11-24 00:00:00",…}
14
:
{firstName: "Замира", lastName: "Калиева", startDate: "2023-11-26 00:00:00",…}
15
:
{firstName: "Замира", lastName: "Калиева", startDate: "2023-11-27 00:00:00",…}
16
:
{firstName: "Замира", lastName: "Калиева", startDate: "2023-11-28 00:00:00",…}
17
:
{firstName: "Замира", lastName: "Калиева", startDate: "2023-11-29 00:00:00",…}
18
:
{firstName: "Замира", lastName: "Калиева", startDate: "2023-11-30 00:00:00",…}
19
:
{firstName: "Замира", lastName: "Калиева", startDate: "2023-12-03 00:00:00",…}
20
:
{firstName: "Замира", lastName: "Калиева", startDate: "2023-12-04 00:00:00",…}
21
:
{firstName: "Замира", lastName: "Калиева", startDate: "2023-12-05 00:00:00",…}
6521
:
[{firstName: "Аида", lastName: "Жекенова", startDate: "2023-11-28 00:00:00",…},…]
0
:
{firstName: "Аида", lastName: "Жекенова", startDate: "2023-11-28 00:00:00",…}
1
:
{firstName: "Аида", lastName: "Жекенова", startDate: "2023-11-29 00:00:00",…}
2
:
{firstName: "Аида", lastName: "Жекенова", startDate: "2023-11-30 00:00:00",…}
3
:
{firstName: "Аида", lastName: "Жекенова", startDate: "2023-12-01 00:00:00",…}
4
:
{firstName: "Аида", lastName: "Жекенова", startDate: "2023-12-03 00:00:00",…}
5
:
{firstName: "Аида", lastName: "Жекенова", startDate: "2023-12-04 00:00:00",…}
6
:
{firstName: "Аида", lastName: "Жекенова", startDate: "2023-12-05 00:00:00",…}

I was trying to fix this issue by changing some option in function of creating chart, I guess there is problem.